# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to aggregate using time buckets. Then, I want to return an array full of the values per day (0 when no document found). The aggeagate function work wondefully, but when I replace the callback (formerly console.log) like this:

```
Star.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      "mod": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("53765a122c0cda28199df3f4"),
      "time_bucket.month": new TimeBucket().month
    }
    },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$time_bucket.day",
      stars: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }

      },
  {
    $sort: {
      '_id': 1
    }
      }],
function (err, mods) {
  console.log(err, mods);
  mods = mods.map(function (model) {
    return model.toObject ? model.toObject() : model
  });
  var i, time, docs = [];
  var hasGap = function (a, b) {
    a = a.replace(/-/g, '');
    b = b.replace(/-/g, '');
    return a - b !== 1
  }

  var process = function (i, mods, docs) {
    if (hasGap(mods[i]._id, mods[i + 1]._id)) {
      docs.push(0);
      return process(i, mods, docs)
    }
    docs.push(mods[i].stars);
    return process(i + 1, mods, docs)

  };
  process(0, mods, docs);
  console.log(docs);
});
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\Me\Nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:245
        throw message;
              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `process` function is recursive and has no path that breaks the recursion by not calling `process` again.  A classic infinite recursion stack overflow.

The solution is to change the `process` function so that it checks for being at the end of the `mods` array of result docs and then simply return at that point instead of calling itself again.

So a check like:

```
if (i >= mods.length) return;
```

Comment: And the solution ?

Comment: @Julien See updated answer. It's hard to be more specific without knowing more about the OP's data.